# wpf converters with different decimal number

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters

I have a lot of numbers to deal with from my UI. I want some of them to be no decimal places, some to be 2 decimals, and others to be however they are entered (3 or 4 decimal places).

I have a converter named DoubleToStringConverter like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(string))]
public class DoubleToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? null : ((double)value).ToString("#,0.##########");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double retValue;
        if (double.TryParse(value as string, out retValue))
        {
            return retValue;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write just one converter to achieve this? It seems there is no way to have a parameterized converter. The StringFormat in xaml seems to conver string to other type of data. It does not allow to display a substring from xaml.

I can only think of making IntegerToStringConverter, Double2ToStringConverter, Double3ToStringConverter, etc. But I'd like to see whether there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Why don't you use the `parameter` to specify your significant digits?

Comment: Yes.  You [can add a parameter to your binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter.aspx).  It's available in the method signature--parameter.  You can convert that to a string, then determine the cast you need to make (int/double/long), then call ToString on it.  use `targetType` on the backside to determine what to parse.  Not sure where you're having an issue here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the number of decimal points to use as the `parameter`, which can then be specified in XAML via [`ConverterParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter.aspx) within the binding.

That being said, for formatting numbers, you don't actually need a converter at all.  Bindings support [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) directly, which can be used to do the formatting entirely in XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TheDoubleValue, StringFormat=0:N2} />
```

Comment: :/ `StringFormat="0:N2"` and `"{" + parameter + "}"` would be easier.

Comment: @Will What do you mean about `"{" + parameter + "}"` being easier?  Good point about the "0:N2".

Comment: Oh, er, constructing the format string in the method body.  Which isn't really necessary here.  Carry on.

Comment: I have this

`<TextBlock.Text><Binding Path="TheDoubleValue" Converter="{StaticResource doubleToStringConverter}" Mode="OneWay" StringFormat="{}{0:N2} Kg"></Binding></TextBlock.Text>`

But the output is like:
50 Kg instead of 50.00 Kg

Comment: @Martin Remove the converter - it's turning your number into a string.

Comment: @Martin Just use `<TextBlock.Text><Binding Path="TheDoubleValue" Mode="OneWay" StringFormat="{}{0:N2} Kg"></Binding>`, or even just: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TheDoubleValue,Mode=OneWay,StringFormat={}{0:N2} Kg}" />`